# Index of duplicates items in Java Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like filter ArrayList by spotting the similar items positions in ArrayList so I can get the index position of duplicate items.

With a list like:

```
List = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'A']
```

I want it to give me:

```
index [0, 2, 5] // A
index [1] // B
index [3] // C
index [4] // E
```

Comment: What you have tried so far??

Comment: I tried to check and find duplicated items and put it in different array then remove the duplication and search again using these values one by one. if value 1 (from the duplicates Array)  matches the value of current index //do something here but sadly it didn't work if statement here runs only once

Comment: Share your code..

Comment: Read guidelines for posting homework questions here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 3):

```
Map<Character, List<Integer>> indexes = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    indexes.computeIfAbsent(list.get(i), c -> new ArrayList<>()).add(i);
}
System.out.println(indexes);
// {A=[0, 2, 5], B=[1], C=[3], E=[4]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] list = {'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'A'};
    Map<Character, List<Integer>> indexes = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
         if(indexes.get(list[i]) != null)
         { 
             List<Integer> indexList=indexes.get(list[i]);
             indexList.add(i);
             indexes.put(list[i],indexList);
         }
         else
         {
            List<Integer> indexList =  new ArrayList<>();
            indexList.add(i);
             indexes.put(list[i],indexList);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(indexes);
    // {E=[4], A=[0, 2, 5], B=[1], C=[3]}
```

Comment: So much redundant code. All you need inside the loop is: `List<Integer> indexList = indexes.get(list[i]); if (indexList == null) indexes.put(list[i], indexList = new ArrayList<>()); indexList.add(i);`

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8+

We can use `Stream`s with [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) to obtain all the indexes of a particular element in a `List`.

```java
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
//...
final Map<Character, List<Integer>> indexMap = IntStream.range(0, list.size()).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(list::get));
//{A=[0, 2, 5], B=[1], C=[3], E=[4]}
//Map of item value to List of indexes at which it occurs in the original List
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ucwi9L)